# MS Query 14 to use data in excel sheet as part of query

Tags: sql, excel, ms-query

We have a student MIS running on SQL Server 2012.  We have multiple spreadsheets extracting data through ODBC connections.  The query is generated in MS Query 2014.  I would like to feed criteria into the Query from a cell in an Excel sheet as the subset of data I would like changes.  For example I have a spreadsheet that extracts all the lessons a year group attend on a particular day.  If I want to change the year group I have to edit the query.  I would like to be able to type the yeargroup into a cell in the worksheet and have it update the data.

Is this possible and can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Its possible use this query:-

```
SELECT *  FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=C:\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sheet1$]
```